# Oracle combines two records in one record despite of Union

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have created two simple queries to combine the records using UNION

However, I faced a problem in one case, the data in the 1st table is exactly like the 2nd one

Then the result appears in one record, not two records as others I need them in separate lines

For example, I have two tables for bank

BankAccount1 & BankAccount2

```
select ID, REF, Amount 
from
    (select ID1, REF1, Amount1 from BankAccount1 
     Union
     ID2, REF2, Amount2 from BankAccount2)
```

The result should be like:

```
ID    REF         Amount
------------------------
1     10101040      200
1     10101040      200
```

but Oracle shows result like this

```
ID    REF        Amount
-------------------------
1     10101040     200
```

What do you recommend to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [The UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE) documentation:

> The `UNION` operator returns only distinct rows that appear in either result, while the `UNION ALL` operator returns all rows. The `UNION ALL` operator does not eliminate duplicate selected rows

So you need to use  `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```sql
SELECT ID1 AS id, REF1 AS ref, Amount1 AS amount
FROM   BankAccount1 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID2, REF2, Amount2
FROM   BankAccount2
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bankaccount1 ( id1, ref1, amount1 ) AS
SELECT 1, 10101040, 200 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE bankaccount2 ( id2, ref2, amount2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 10101040, 200 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID |      REF | AMOUNT
> -: | -------: | -----:
>  1 | 10101040 |    200
>  1 | 10101040 |    200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d21d1f67297562e0ea23f601c618fc3c)*

*(Note: Your query is syntactically invalid as you need a `SELECT` after the `UNION` and the column names will be the taken from the first `SELECT` of the `UNION` and the outer `SELECT` would expect the columns `ID1`, `REF1`, `Amount1` rather than `ID`, `REF`, `Amount`.)*

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` since `union` returns distinct rows:

```
select ID1, REF1, Amount1 from BankAccount1 
Union all
select ID2, REF2, Amount2 from BankAccount2
```